# SUMO: How to add new routing algorithm

Tags: routes, simulation, veins, sumo

I'm using Veins 4.6, SUMO 0.30.0 and OMNET++ 5.1.1 for performance analysis of multiple routing algorithms. To complete my analysis beside [four routing algorithms](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Routing#Routing_Algorithms) available in SUMO, I need to add a new one [**An efficient routing algorithm based on ant colony optimisation for VANETs**](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7807858) which should be used to find best path (if value is passed in --routing-algorithm parameter or mentioned in *.sumocfg file). For example:

```
<routing>
    <routing-algorithm value="aco"/>
    <device.rerouting.probability value="1"/>       
</routing>
```

No guide is available even in [How Tos](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Developer/Main#How_Tos) section of SUMO developers guide to add new routing protocol. Any direction from where to start?

Comment: Is it possible that the algorithm in the cited paper is more about routing in a communication network and not vehicle routing?

Comment: The algorithm is Meta Heuristic in nature, so can be used for vehicle routing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best idea is probably to make a copy of [src/utils/vehicle/DijkstraRouter.h](https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/blob/master/src/utils/vehicle/DijkstraRouter.h) and modify essentially the compute method there.